# activating postgres on ubuntu with an error "could not connect to database postgres"

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu

When I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my windows laptop I tried to activate postgres.
I went to terminal and I ran the following commands.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo passwd postgres
Enter new UNIX password: 123123
Retype new UNIX password: 123123
sudo -u postgres createuser -P db_owner
Enter password for new role: 123123
Enter it again: 123123
Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y
```

Then the terminal gave me the following error:

```
createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Note that this is a new install Ubuntu 13.10 and I haven't done any thing on it yet and this is the first time that i use Ubuntu ever

Comment: I don't know Ubuntu (or Linux that is) - but does `install postgresql` also initialize a data directory (using `initdb`)? If not, then Postgres can't be running and you'll need to do that manually: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/creating-cluster.html

Comment: thank you but i tried it and it didn't work
i'm searching for a step-by-step manual to do this because i have never used Ubuntu befor

Comment: See [Cannot connect to PostgreSQL server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/389459/) on askubuntu.com